# Error: Could not find router reducer in state tree, it must be mounted under "router"

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router

The above error occurred in the  component:
    in ConnectedRouter 
    in ConnectedRouterWithContext 
    in ConnectFunction
    in Provider
I am stuck in a error saying  Could not find router reducer in state tree, it must be mounted under "router"

This is my store.js file.....

```
import storage from 'redux-persist/es/storage';
import { apiMiddleware } from 'redux-api-middleware';
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from 'redux';
import { createFilter   } from 'redux-persist-transform-filter';
import { persistReducer, persistStore } from 'redux-persist';
import { routerMiddleware } from 'react-router-redux';
import rootReducer from './redux/reducers';
import { combineReducers } from 'redux-immutable';
import { connectRouter, RouterState } from 'connected-react-router/immutable';


export default (history) => {
    const persistedFilter = createFilter(
      'auth', ['access', 'refresh']);

    const reducer = persistReducer(
      {
        key: 'polls',
        storage: storage,
        whitelist: ['auth'],
        transforms: [persistedFilter]
      },
      rootReducer)

    const store = createStore(
      reducer, {},

      applyMiddleware(
        apiMiddleware, 
        routerMiddleware(history))

    )
    persistStore(store)
    return store
  }
```

This is how my index.js is

```
const history = createHistory()
const store = configureStore(history)

ReactDOM.render((
  <Provider store={store}>
  <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/login/" component={Login} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/" component={App}/>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 2):

At first, you should add a router in the reducer.

```
const createRootReducer = (history) => combineReducers({
  router: connectRouter(history),
  ... // rest of your reducers
})
export default createRootReducer
```

If you're using react-router-dom@5.x.x then you should use history@4.10.1 because the latest version of history (v5) only works with react-router-dom@6.x.x